# Flask-Stormpath Token based authentication

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0, stormpath, flask-oauthlib

I am trying to implement token based authentication for my Flask REST API. I am using Stormpath as my third-party authentication service.

I looked into `flask-stormpath` built on top of `flask-login`. Looks like it uses password based authentication as they are trying to maintain session on the server. Also, the documentation doesn't provide me enough information.

Do we have a flask integration for stormpath token based authentication ? 
If yes, can someone point me to a sample code.

I have already gone through the `stormpath/flask-stormpath-sample` on github, which again maintains sessions in server.

References:

https://stormpath.com,

https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-flask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here is the way I am currently using until [rdegges](https://stackoverflow.com/users/194175/rdegges) shall build this feature into `flask-stormpath`.

You will need stormpath python sdk latest version and wraps from func tools.

```
from stormpath.api_auth import (PasswordGrantAuthenticator, RefreshGrantAuthenticator, JwtAuthenticator)
from functools import wraps
```

You can create your application as such.

```
stormpathClient = Client(id=KEYS['STORMPATH_ID'], secret=KEYS['STORMPATH_SECRET'])
stormpathApp = stormpathClient.applications.search('your-application')[0]
```

This decorator shall help you with securing endpoints.

```
def tokenRequired(func):
    """
        Decorator to apply on all routes which require tokens.
    """

    @wraps(func)
    def wrappingFunc():
        #check the auth header of the request for a bearer token.
        authHeader = request.headers.get('Authentication')

        #make sure that the string is a bearer type.
        if len(authHeader)<8 or (not authHeader[:7] == 'Bearer ') or (
                not authHeader):
            return Response("401 Unauthorized",401)
        authToken = authHeader[7:]

        try:
            authenticator = JwtAuthenticator(stormpathApp)
            authResult = authenticator.authenticate(authToken)
            request.vUser = authResult.account
        except:
            return Response("403 Forbidden",403)

        return func()

    return wrappingFunc

#Use this decorator like below.

@flaskApp.route('/secure-route',methods=['GET','POST'])
@tokenRequired
def secureEndpoint():

    # return JSON based response 
    return Response("This is secure Mr." + request.vUser.given_name   ,200)
```

Let me know in the comments if someone wishes to know the token issuing and refreshing end points as well.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of the Flask-Stormpath library. The answer is no. I'm actually working on a new release of the library (coming out in a month or so) that will provide this functionality by default, but right now it only supports session based authentication.

Comment: does it offer support now ? (4 years later)

Comment: @rdegges , Can you please look into the temporary way i am using currently ( in an answer below ) and make comments.